# if-statement in a for(each)-loop. continue vs nothing

Tags: php, performance, if-statement, for-loop, continue

Let's consider following array:

```php
$data = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => '0',
        'guid' => '22dd39bf-f6d6-4283-b87c-370354a7c2dd',
        'age' => '32',
        'name' => 'Harriet Vazquez',
        'gender' => 'female',
        'email' => 'harrietvazquez@applica.com',
        'tags' => array(
            '0' => 'sit',
            '1' => 'mollit',
            '2' => 'cillum',
            '3' => 'irure',
        ),
        'friends' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'id' => '0',
                'name' => 'Long Dejesus',
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Carrillo Hodge',
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'Coffey Greene',
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'name' => 'Stephanie Chavez',
            ),
            '4' => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'name' => 'Richmond Mitchell',
            ),
        )
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'guid' => '3df3ae55-03f3-4d7d-9c70-c7010a100886',
        'age' => '36',
        'name' => 'David Lynch',
        'gender' => 'male',
        'email' => 'davidlynch@applica.com',
        'tags' => array(
            '0' => 'id',
            '1' => 'ad',
            '2' => 'labore',
            '3' => 'ad',
            '4' => 'veniam',
            '5' => 'nulla',
        ),
        'friends' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'id' => '0',
                'name' => 'Diana Watts',
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Patty Crawford',
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'Terrell Larson',
            ),
        )
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'guid' => 'da2c9f3f-ac85-4dfd-a43c-e55e476596ca',
        'age' => '25',
        'name' => 'Hardin Murphy',
        'gender' => 'male',
        'email' => 'hardinmurphy@applica.com',
        'tags' => array(
            '0' => 'laborum',
            '1' => 'labore',
            '2' => 'dolor',
            '3' => 'excepteur',
            '4' => 'est',
        ),
        'friends' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'id' => '0',
                'name' => 'Mandy Roberts',
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Walker Young',
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'Middleton Baldwin',
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'name' => 'Tillman Harmon',
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Let us now create a loop with some conditions

```php
$accepted = array('age', 'name', 'email');
foreach ($data as $idx => $row) 
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
    {
        if(!is_array($value) && in_array($key, $accepted))
        {
            var_dump($value) . PHP_EOL;

        }
    }
}
```

Code above will produce output like this:

```
string(2) "32"
string(15) "Harriet Vazquez"
string(26) "harrietvazquez@applica.com"
string(2) "36"
string(11) "David Lynch"
string(22) "davidlynch@applica.com"
string(2) "25"
string(13) "Hardin Murphy"
string(24) "hardinmurphy@applica.com"
```

**And now the question**: 
Is there are any differences (and i mean performance) if I'll add an `continue` statement within `else` statement ?

```php
$accepted = array('age', 'name', 'email');
foreach ($data as $idx => $row) 
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
    {
        if(!is_array($value) && in_array($key, $accepted))
        {
            var_dump($value) . PHP_EOL;

        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? In your example your `continue` is redundant. It will have negligible impact on performance. Is there some bigger issue here?

Comment: @MikeW I'm trying to find out how to use `continue` correctly. I saw the code like this and I was wondering myself if there any reasons to do so... As you have already said, it's redundant und seems to be completely useless

Comment: Well, I think you've found a way to use `continue` **incorrectly**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue skips the rest of the code in the current iteration, since there is no code to skip, your second solution will be insignificantly slower (one more operation, and it's useless).

From the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) :

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the
>   current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition
>   evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

It it basically a goto that goes to the end of your current loop iteration, it would be useful in a case like this  :

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
{
    if ($value == "whatever")
    {
        continue;
    }

    function1($value);
    // Whatever code here

    // The continue will skip the above code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a slight performance difference: The latter version will run O(1) slower, for a very small value of 1.

The reason is, that the parsing (or might as well call it "compiling") stage of the script will run a tiny bit slower, but I am quite sure the bytecode from both versions will have identical runtime properties (if it is not identical).

Comment: Not only the compiling, PHP will have to execute continue, which will probably do nothing but there will be a condition to evaluate.

Comment: PHP will execute a continue in both cases. Every loop ends with one, that is put there during compilation. The condition is evaluated anyway (it belongs to the `IF`, not to the `ELSE`)